# Fill reactive form initial data from service

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

Using Angular 7 and Reactive forms I have the following on a component:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.postForm = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    categoryId: [''],  
    title: [''],
    content: ['']
  });

}

getPost(postId: number) : Observable<Post> {

  return this.postService.getByPostId(postId);

}
```

Where PostService's GetByPostId method is as follows:

```
public getByPostId(postId: number): Observable<Post> {

  return this.httpClient.get<Post>(`posts/${postId}`);

}
```

The postService returns one Post which interface is:

```
interface Post {
  id: number;
  categoryId: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
}
```

What is the correct way to fill the form data from what getPost returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do that is using `patchValue` method:

```
updateProfile() {
 this.profileForm.patchValue({
    firstName: 'Nancy',
    address: {
      street: '123 Drew Street'
    }
  });
}
```

More Information: [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#partial-model-updates)